# How to delete alll es index templates ? (Elasticserch 6.1.3)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-5

I try to delete all templates in my local instance .but it fail and I got this message .How do I delete all templates ?  I don't understand this error.

My query :

```
DELETE /_template
```

error :

```
{
 "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_template] and method [DELETE], allowed: [GET]",
"status": 405}
```

Comment: You have to specify template name also like `DELETE /_template/temp1`. This is why you are getting the error

Answer (score 4):

this seemed to work for me on linux to delete all templates:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:9200/_template/*"
```

this is with elasticsearch 2.4

Answer (score 2):

There is no such possibility to remove all the templates at once.

You can first get all the existing templates list with:

```
GET /_template
```

and next remove one by one using their names:

```
DELETE /_template/NAME_OF_THE_FIRST_TEMPLATE
DELETE /_template/NAME_OF_THE_SECOND_TEMPLATE
DELETE /_template/NAME_OF_THE_THIRD_TEMPLATE
...
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: Above but with curl, jq and xargs `curl http://localhost:9200/_template | jq -r 'keys[]' | xargs -I {} curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/_template/{}"`